# Can't manage to figure out the syntax of C++ lamda expression as a method's parameter

Tags: c++, unreal-engine4

**Question:**

How do you pass a lambda expression into a function. for example:

```
int GetCoolInt()
{
    int a = 3;

    return AddToInt( [a] (int b) {
        a += b;
    });    
}

int AddToInt(int func(int output))
{
    return func(3);
}

int output = GetCoolInt();
```

**Context of my issue:**

I have the following 2 methods:

`FindPlayerStartByTag` calls `FindActor` to use logic that will be used in other methods.

```
//template <typename T>
APlayerStart* FindPlayerStartByTag(FName tag)
{
    return FindActor<APlayerStart>(tag, [tag](TObjectIterator<APlayerStart> actor) {
        APlayerStart* playerStart;
        if (actor->PlayerStartTag == tag)
        {
            playerStart = *actor;
        }
        return playerStart;
    });
}
```

This method is the logic to find a specific object in an iterator with the help of the `FindPlayerStartByTag` logic

```
template <typename T>
T* FindActor(FName tag, T* func(TObjectIterator<T> actor))
{
    T* returnValue;

    if (!tag.IsNone())
    {
        // Search for actor
        for (TObjectIterator<T> itr; itr; ++itr)
        {
            if (itr->IsA(T::StaticClass()))
            {
                returnValue = func(itr);
                if (returnValue)
                {
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

I currently have this error:

[image]

I'm confused as to what it means, considering a third method:

```
template <typename T>
T* FindActorByTag(FName tag)
{
    return FindActor<T>(tag, [tag](TObjectIterator<AActor> actor)
    {
        T* foundActor;
        for (FName currentActorTag : actor->Tags)
        {
            if (tag == currentActorTag)
            {
                foundActor = *actor;
            }
        }
        return foundActor;
    });
}
```

compiles just fine.

I can see that by adding template `<typename T>` gets rid of the error (see the `//template <typename T>`, but i don't need this as in the case of APlayerStart, i am already aware of what type the method needs to be.

Anyone help explain this?

Thanks!

**Edit:**

Here is a version of the method that i was using before i refactored into here:

```
APlayerStart* FindPlayerStartByTag(FName tag)
{
    /*return FindActor<APlayerStart>(tag, [tag](TObjectIterator<APlayerStart> actor) {
        APlayerStart* playerStart;
        if (actor->PlayerStartTag == tag)
        {
            playerStart = *actor;
        }
        return playerStart;
    });*/

    APlayerStart* returnValue;

    if (!tag.IsNone())
    {
        // Search for actor
        for (TObjectIterator<APlayerStart> itr; itr; ++itr)
        {
            if (itr->IsA(APlayerStart::StaticClass()) && itr->PlayerStartTag == tag)
            {
                returnValue = *itr;
            }
        }
    }

    return returnValue;
}
```

but compiles.

**Edit 2:**

This is how i intend on using the methods:

```
PlayerStart = ActorHelper->FindPlayerStartByTag(PlayerStartTag);
ATreasureChestActor* treasureChestActor = ActorHelper->FindActorByTag<ATreasureChestActor>(TreasureActorTagName);
```

**Edit 3:**

The issue seems to be coming from the closure usage!

This is with the use of a closure variable:

[image]

and this is without:

[image]

Comment: My apologies, is there something more I can add to help you guys n girls out. I can see the down  votes so am worried I've missed something obvious out

Comment: Just seems really hard to follow - you've dumped a few functions on us without any context or coherence. Could you instead present a clear [MCVE]? What are you trying to do? What are all these types that you haven't introduced? And avoid phrases like "does a dookie" as I have no idea what that means... use clear English.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Thanks, i'll try and make a version of the issue that doesn't include domain detail. Although i had given that a try and was struggling to see where the problem was so couldn't reproduce it hehe. Thanks

Comment: Well, that's the point, isn't it? If _you_ as the code author cannot come up with an MCVE that reproduces the problem, then by definition there is certainly insufficient information for us randomers to do so! So you have to put in that work and reach that level before bringing it to us otherwise we are not going to be able to help. Good luck!

Comment: haha, for sure. I was hoping it was more of a stupid syntax issue and someone would be like, dude, you have no idea how to use lambda expressions :D, this is how you do it. Alas, i guess it's a bit more of an annoying problem

Comment: please don't post print screens of code or error messages.

Comment: The answer doesn't go in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your post is still a mess, with 4 different versions of the same issue. I will focus on the first code snippet as it seems to be the closest one to a [MCVE] and I will clarify how to properly use lambdas and function objects.

```
int AddToInt(int func(int output))
```

This is a little bit misleading. I suggest changing it to the equivalent, but more used:

```
int AddToInt(int (*func)(int))
```

This means: declaring a function named `AddToInt` which:

- accepts a parameter of type "pointer to function accepting an int and returning an int" and
- returns an `int`.

As you can see, your function accept a classic C function pointer. It won't accept a function object of any type. To note here is that lambdas without capture can be converted to a function pointer.

For instance keeping the above declaration:

```
AddToInt([](int b) { return b + 1; }); // ok, non-capturing lambda conversion to function pointer

AddToInt([a](int b) { return a + b; }); // error cannot convert capturing lambda to function pointer
```

The reason is simple to understand. A non-capturing lambda can be equivalent to a free function, but a capturing lambda has a state (formed by the capture set), so it is "more" than a simple, classical free function.

As you can see, accepting function pointers is very much an archaic idiom because of these limitations (and don't even think of passing any kind of function object - e.g. a class with `operator()` defined).

For accepting any kind of callable object you generally have two options: the general template or the standard `std::function` object.

### Template object

```
template <class Fn>
int AddToInt1(Fn func)
{
    return func(3);
}
```

Now you can call `AddToInt1` with any kind of callable. Depending of the type of the deduced `Fn` type you can have zero overhead with this method. A downside is that you can accept any type, including non-callable ones, or ones with incorrect parameter or return types. Concepts will alleviate most of these downsides.

```
AddToInt1([](int b) { return b + 1; }); // OK

AddToInt1([a](int b) { return a + b; }); // OK
```

You also might want to add perfect forwarding (omitted in the example for brevity).

### `std::function`

The other route is to use `std::function`:

```
int AddToInt2(std::function<int(int)> func)
```

The disadvantage here is the heaviness of the `std::function` object. It uses type erasure and that adds a significant amount of performance penalty (which can be perfectly acceptable depending on your usage).

```
AddToInt2([](int b) { return b + 1; }); // OK

AddToInt2([a](int b) { return a + b; }); // OK
```

---

Now, once you get the gist of the above there are some more problems with your code you need to figure out:

```
[a] (int b) { a += b;};
```

First of all, are you aware that this lambda does not return anything? Furthermore it tries to modify the captured by value `a` which is illegal, as the lambda's `operator()` is `const` by default for good reason. If you want the lambda to modify the outer `a` captured variable, then you need to capture it by reference:

```
[&a] (int b) { a += b;};
```

And now you have to really really be careful to not end up with a dangling reference.

But I suspect you meant:

```
AddToInt([a] (int b) { return a + b;});
```

But that is just pure speculation on my part.

---

Here is a fully working example:

```
template <class Fn>
int AddToInt1(Fn func)
{
    return func(3);
}

int AddToInt2(std::function<int (int)> func)
{
    return func(3);
}

int GetCoolInt()
{
    int a = 3;

    return AddToInt1([a] (int b) { return a + b;}); // OK
    //return AddToInt2([a] (int b) { return a + b;}); // OK
}
```

---

There are some important points I just mentioned here, but elaborating on them would be equivalent to writing a full tutorial on lambdas and beyond, which is out of the scope of this site. In conclusion you have to study the subject on your own.

Comment: You are a gentleman and a scholar! The issue with my code was highlighted with the more general declaration of a templated type. This was really wonderfully written. Thank you so so much. I've added my solution to the original question.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 you are welcome. For the reputation you have you should know by now that you shouldn't include solutions in the question.

Comment: Thanks dude/dude-ess. In fairness, the lack of markdown in the comments makes it hard to share the discovered answer to my particular problem. so i added it to the question. Thanks for the tip in the future. Re "gentleman" i meant to put "gentleman/gentlelady"

Comment: Darn, I can't seem to find the way I solved this now. did someone remove it from my answer? I could have sworn I added it above.

Comment: @Jimmyt1988 yes, your question was rolled back because on SO a question should not contain the answer. If you want to post your own answer you need to add an actual answer to your question. You can view your previous version of your post by viewing its history (click on "Edited by ...")

Comment: Ahh. Thanks for the tip. Thought I'd lost it then haha. Understood